# How to echo text into a file where the file prefix consists of one or more env. vars with spaces in them?

Tags: shell, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, dos

The 2 env. vars set previously

```
overall_timestamp_first=2011-03-14 20:40:49
overall_timestamp_last=2011-03-15 02:55:20
```

The command in a batch file I'm trying to get to use to create a file using the env. vars.

```
echo Application Error Event Analysis > "%overall_timestamp_first% - %overall_timestamp_last%.doc"
```

Answer (score 1):

The colons in the filename are the problem. They're not legal in filenames in DOS/Windows.

Change your timestamp format to `hh.mm.ss` and this will work:

```
set overall_timestamp_first=2011-03-14 20.40.49
set overall_timestamp_last=2011-03-14 21.00.00
set overall_filename="%overall_timestamp_first%-%overall_timestamp_last%.txt"
@echo Application Error Event Analysyis > %overall_filename%
```

Output on my machine:

```
D:\Temp>dir 2*
 Volume in drive D is Something
 Volume Serial Number is ABCD-DCBA

 Directory of D:\Temp

04/15/2011  09:03 PM                36 2011-03-14 20.40.49-2011-03-14 21.00.00.txt
               1 File(s)             36 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  204,289,437,696 bytes free
```

Answer (score 1):

File names cannot contain `:` on Windows. This has nothing to do with the spaces (which you correctly solved by enclosing the file name in quotes).

So remove the colons (or replace them by another, valid character) from your variables; either when setting them or directly in your later line:

```
echo Application Error Event Analysis > "%overall_timestamp_first::=% - %overall_timestamp_last::=%.doc"
```